# How to use maven-antrun-plugin for phase exec

Tags: maven

Is it possible to use maven-antrun-plugin for the exec phase/goal.

currently I use the following but it does not work:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>exec</id>
        <phase>exec</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <target
            name='Exec'
          >
            <exec
              executable='${env.COMSPEC}'
              osfamily='winnt'
            >
              <arg
                value='/c'
              ></arg>
              <arg
                value='src\\main\\scripts\\Exec.cmd'
              ></arg>
            </exec>
            <exec
              executable='src/main/scripts/Exec.command'
              osfamily='unix'
            ></exec>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Of course if anybody knows a way around the ${env.COMSPEC} hack on windows that would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin is used to run an arbitrary executable and not an `ant task` which should ideally not have OS-specific check.

Perhaps you should look at [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)?

Comment: Of course I looked at the exec-maven-plugin plug-in. The “for phase exec” is a dead give away ;-)

BTW: I don't run an executable but an external script file. And for a script not only the script is OS dependent but the call itself as well as Windows does not support a shebang.

And for this I am migrating away from exec-maven-plugin.